# DotNetBar vs. Krypton

Tags: winforms, user-controls, krypton-toolkit

I am considering buying a WinForm controls suite and have narrowed it down to Component Factory's [Krypton Suite](http://www.componentfactory.com/) and DevComponent's [DotNetBar](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/).  My question is: Are any of you familiar with both suites, and which would you recommend?  DotNetBar looks like it has a few more components, but Krypton Suite looks like it may have a more professional look-and-feel.  Any comments on these areas?

PS: I know that there are several other really good ones out there (DevExpress, Telerik, etc.), however these all cost a bit more than I'm willing to spend.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go for dotnetbar @ $270. Else go for devexpress @ $800. The difference between krypton and devexpress is $300. But in this 'extra' you get charting, reports, printing, olap .. etc. So I would suggest dotnetbar or devexpress.

Trial versions are available for all. You can check out demos for every component and decide.

Answer (score 5):

Krypton Toolkit is now Open source

https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton